# How to check if there already exists an id in a main table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I was wondering if there's a way to check an existing id in the main table when using temporary table,then use another id for inserting records.Since it may cause error for using the same id in the main table.
Is there a way to do that?I'm using access and works fine with temp table,but i need to check if there's an answer.

Comment: Wanna post a query, table info, results-expected...anything?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a GUID?  May be what you need.

however you might try something like this:
SQL:

declare @id int
set @id=1

while exists (select 1 from TABLE1 where id=@id)
begin
set @id = @id+1
end

I hope this helps,
-Thomas
RosSQL.blogspot.com

Comment: I'm using access with vb.net,i think you wrote works on sql server.Can you write a sql for access?